# Getting started with UIAutomation

Tags: wpf, ui-automation

I'm trying to find a good resource to get started with UIAutomation. I need to simulate mouse input in a WPF application. Are there any good examples out there? I couldn't find any, and the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx) seems too extensive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UI Automation is not really intended to simulate mouse clicks. It is meant to expose the user interface in a programmatically-accessible fashion.

It organizes controls in a hierarchy that can be easily traversed/navigated by screen readers or similar applications. And, it uses [control patterns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752362.aspx) to allow users to interact with the controls.

A Button for example can expose the [InvokePattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.invokepattern.aspx) via it's automation peer. You can simulate a click using the [Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.invokepattern.invoke.aspx) method on that pattern. This is done independently of the mouse, so there would be no mouse over/enter/leave/down events, just a Click event.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Do you think I can achieve what I want with UIAutomation or should I use something more appropiate? In case you recommend UIAutomation, do you have some guidelines I could follow to get this done?

Comment: @alfonso - You'd have to resort to the Win32 API, such as [SendInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310.aspx), to achieve that. [This project](http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/) may be of interest.

Comment: Great! I'll investigate it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [mouse class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.uitesting.mouse.aspx) with UIAutomation. But as CodeNaked rightly said, we should use UIAutomation patterns for mouse like operations and it is not good practice to use mouse class.

You can refer [this code project article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33049/WPF-UI-Automation) to start with UIAutomation.

I hope this will help you.